# Modeling Waffle Shape of Cone

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, mesh, edges

So I have completed a model of an ice cream cone, but I'm stumped on how to achieve the waffle pattern. What would be the best way to go about this?

[image]

Is Sculpting with an alpha good? Or can you achieve this with the poke tool? I tried leaving criss cross edges but it just didn't want to work.

Any help would be appreciated!
(If you need Blend file, let me know! I don't know how to upload .blend files here yet)

Comment: My feeling is that it would be easier to do with a displacement modifier or with a relief map on the texture hooked up to the displacement socket of the material.

Comment: @cegaton Okay, cool...and do you think it's able to be achieved with the preset Textures Blender has to offer, or should I create / look for one? Totally forgot about displacing it!

Comment: @Art Jr. If you want to upload .blend files in future use Blend Exchange (http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Comment: @PaulGonet Hey Paul! Thanks for the tip, definitely will be sure to use it in the future! Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You may model it using ***poke*** and ***bevel*** tools.
[image]

Select the faces you want to put the pattern on and hide the rest of the mesh with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to ***poke faces***. Select vertical edges (select one of them, go to *Select*-->*Select Similar*-->*Face Angles*), then *dissolve* them (except for top and bottom ones) with <kbd>X</kbd>-->*Dissolve Edges*. Do the same with horizontal ones. You now have the pattern base.
[image]

Select all the faces, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and drag the mouse to achieve the desired patern's thickness. Inverse the selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>. Extrude and scale faces inwards (<kbd>E</kbd>,<kbd>I</kbd>,<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>).
[image]

Unhide everything (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>), select the pattern except for very top and bottom edges. Go to *edge selection* and press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to crease it.
[image]
[image]

Finally, you may bake created pattern to the low-poly version of your ice cone (bake normals) and apply it as a normal texture.

Answer (score 11):

Personally I would go with *Bump*.

Here it is setup with uv and nodes:

[image]

I've created this texture in Adobe Illustrator with *Rectangular Grid Tool*.

### UPDATE:

With closer look I've found that some of relief is squashed so I've added some loop cuts to control it with UV maps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow! That's also Amazing too! Thank you so much for the contribution!!