# How to model/apply a rhomboid pattern on a cylinder? (Sword hilt modeling)

Tags: modeling

I'm modelling a Vibrosword from Star Wars and I can't figure out how to model the rhomboidal incisions on the hilt.

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Not the same but the technique detaled here may help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58959/how-to-model-braided-nylon-sleeve/58963#58963

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly different technique, not necessarily quicker, but has fewer steps.

Subdivide your cylinder vertically the number of desired times with a *Loopcut*.

With all loops selected start the *Bevel* operator, switch to *Percent* mode, turn on *Vertex Only*, and increase the value to 50% so it goes half-way through the edges.

Don't forget to remove all doubles in the end.

**Disclaimer**: You might end up with some NGons in the ends that might call for some cleanup if you want proper topology.

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant. A brand new method for me. Tried it using only keyboard shortcuts. Here's how to achieve it: After subdividing a cylinder with *Ctrl+R* you press *A* twice to select the whole mesh, then *Ctrl+B*, *V*, *M* (three times) and you type 50. Finally you press W to remove doubles:) (works on all different sized cylinders). Thnx Duarte! Still wonder if there's a faster method though ;P.

Answer (score 3):

Subdivide your cylinder vertically the number of desired times with a *Loopcut*.

Select all faces and use the *Poke* operator to turn them into rhombus.

Using the *Select Similar* operator (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> by default) select all horizontal edges and erase them with the *Dissolve* option, making sure you keep the ones defining the cylinder top and bottom edges.

Repeat the process for the vertical edges by *Select Similar* then *Dissolve*.
Done!

[image]

Comment: Duarte, why are you copying the solution from my first .gif posted here?: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61785/modeling-waffle-shape-of-cone Just kidding :). Good answer here. I wonder if there is a quicker way to achieve this kind of subdivision though. It would be great to have the e.g. 'poked cylinder' (you name it) object available via Mesh Extras menu.

Comment: Haha hadn't seen that one before, upvoted. Great modelling BTW, icecream cone looks fantastic, now it made me hungry. Now that you mentioned it, I just found a different method

Comment: I wonder what you use to make gifs like this one under 3MB

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers/

Answer (score 0):

I can make easier case 2

Just perform *poke face* (<kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>P</kbd>) and *tris to quads*(<kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>J</kbd>)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)