# Need help with displacement mapping please!

Tags: uv, normal-map, displacement

I got a new job in, and I need to make a design for 3D printing. It's for a growing pot, and everything is allright, but I have no idea why I can't make my displacement modifyer to work.

This is the reference photo: 
[image]

Here you will fin the project uv-mapped and with the displacement pattern for the ingravings:
blender exchange file: 
[image]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/c1meqh0khlvv0vm/8813-058_Hvidestenpotter_Ingraved.zip?dl=0

I would really like to know how to use the displacement mapping, as it would make future work a lot easier, I just can't find anything on the problem here :/

Kind Regards
Anders

Comment: Find (or create) a cross pattern texture, add it to the material and mix its influence to be 100% at the top and 0% in the bottom (e.g. with ColorRamp which will work like a gradient making the bottom part of the image of needed color) or mix that gradient into the texture itself

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61785/modeling-waffle-shape-of-cone

Comment: I've added the blend-exchange .blend file now Ray :)

Comment: Mr Zak I'm not totally sure about what you mean. Can you try to explain your solution a bit more detailed :)

Comment: Anyone? Still need help :/..