# How to make this kind of wire mesh on the side of the object?

Tags: modeling

[image]

So, how can i make this kind of wire mesh on the side of object like this parfume bottle that has a rounded edge? i tried making it using precise calculation (exact size for each subdivision and face so the result is a square subdivision) and a manual modeling.

[image: The result of doing it as described]

But is there a better way? because with wiremesh modifier, you can't apply it to an edge with no face (see the edge of the wiremesh on the bottle). Or do i have to model it manually?

Thanks.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61785/modeling-waffle-shape-of-cone/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116466/easy-way-to-model-spiral-engraving-knurling-that-is-usually-used-on-metal-for https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58959/how-to-model-braided-nylon-sleeve https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/294248/creating-knurl-on-certain-faces-using-geometry-nodes

Answer (score 2):

As Harry says you can easily model it [like that](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116466/easy-way-to-model-spiral-engraving-knurling-that-is-usually-used-on-metal-for).

If you want to use a modifer, you can try the *Skin* modifier. First create this mesh:

[image]

Then give it a *Skin* modifier (with *Branch Smoothing* at 1) and a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. To change the thickness select all in *Edit* mode and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>:

[image]

Comment: The unsubdivide iteration=1 is really cool and creates this diagonal mesh :D https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/116466/easy-way-to-model-spiral-engraving-knurling-that-is-usually-used-on-metal-for

Comment: Yes sure, it's just if he wants to use a modifier   ;)